Unable to interact with desktop
This issue started about a month ago but the frequency has increased a lot these days.
There seems to be an invisible layer above my desktop only on 75% of the right side of my desktop
Un-interactable section of my desktop
A restart fixes this but still occurs again after some time.
Restarting explorer does not fix this.
Similar mentions of this here and I've tried quite a few fixes like this but this still keeps happening.
I'm assuming a new Windows feature might be triggering this like Copilot possibly but I'm not sure how to fix this
Interacting with my desktop, normally.
Right-click doesn't work, can't click on any files, can't drag and drop, only on certain sections of my desktop.

It seems Microsoft Edge Version 125.0.2535.67 (Official build) (64-bit) might be the cause of this. After closing Edge (completely, even from background) seems to make my desktop interactable again.
